# Which hook should I use to capture $_POST('password') via profile update and password reset

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions, user-registration, password

I need to rehash the password which the user entered during Wordpress registration (I use WooCommerce)

I'm successfully able to do this with the following:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    }

}
```

However, I need to do this for 2 more occasions, **profile update** and **reset password**

I wrote:

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['password'] ) || '' == $_POST['password'] ) {
        return;
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    $x = $_POST['password'];
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert('.$x.')';
    echo '</script>';


    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

It doesn' work at all.

**UPDATE**

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', (string) $_POST['password']);
    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

It works but `$_POST['password']` or `$_POST['pass1']` returns nothing.

Comment: I think you want to use the `personal_options_update` action instead of (or in addition to) `profile_update`.

Comment: the profile_update works right now, the problem is I cant access the $_POST['password'] or $_POST['pass1'], it returns nothing

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: You need to check the specific input field name that is being used for the screen in question.  For example, if you're using the WooCommerce account page, the password is "password_1".

Comment: Im exactly updating password via woocommerce account detail page

Comment: its interesting because when I used account registration during checkout in woocommerce the POST was $_POST['account_password'] , it seems its different every where, where should I look to check it ? I read almost all the hooks!

Comment: Thanks man , It worked, if you send the answer I will accept it right away, Is it safe to write this code ? I mean in the future updates of woocommerce they use same POST methods with the same name ? Im trying to write compatible codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have to look at the name of the input you're trying to pick up via `$_POST`.  It's not always consistent across forms.  In the case of the WooCommerce password change form, the input name for the new password field is 'password_1' so that's what you need to pick up via `$_POST`:

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
       update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', (string) $_POST['password_1']);
    }
    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

When in doubt on the input tag name, use the browser inspector.  While hovering your mouse over the field in question, right click and select "inspect".  This will highlight the HTML for that field in the inspector and you can look at the value for "name".  That's the value you need to use in `$_POST`.

Also note the addition of checking that the action is not run on the dashboard (admin) side (`is_admin()`).  WooCommerce is using the same action hook as WP to consolidate (something that it sounds like you *don't* want to do).

Comment: now I have another problem , when I update any other info from Admin panel , it rewrite on user_pass2 that I created on meta data !

Comment: any work around for this? I used edit_user_profile_update , but it didnt work at all

Comment: Yes - they both apply the same action hook.  If you don't want that to happen, you can apply the `is_admin()` conditional tag as a check.  I'll edit the code example above so that it reflects that.

Comment: thanks very much, I was about to edit pluggable.php from core wordpress files as this article suggest to get the raw password and store it in database
http://qnimate.com/find-your-wordpress-users-password-2/

Comment: whats your opinion ? is it better to edit core wordpress? I mean I know its bad but in a long run, after plugin updates or changing some plugins or add ons do you think its better to capture raw password from the wordpress core files ?

Comment: DO NOT under any circumstances edit core files directly.  If you're making a change to a pluggable function, the way to do that is to load your function as a plugin - changing it in the actual core file is not what's intended (i.e. that's not "plugging" the function).

Comment: BTW... I just worked off your example. Keep in mind that as written, you're storing a plain text version of the password, which is not a good idea. The fact that I didn't hash it is only because I was working from your example, it isn't condoning storing a plain text password value. Once tested and working, you should be hashing it.

Comment: no Im not, its just in this code example, Im storing another hash version for another app credential which has another way of hashing method

Comment: so based on your opinion, I believe as long as I use hash version in db and dont edit core files, Im on the safe side

Comment: That is correct! ;-)